# These Python functions don't have running times as expected

Tags: python, algorithm

(I'm not sure if this question belongs here or CS forum. I kept it here because it has Python-specific code. Please migrate if needed!) I'm studying algorithms these days, using Python as my tool of choice. Today, I wanted to plot the running times three variations of a simple problem: Compute the prefix average of a given sequence (list).

Here are the three variations:

```
import timeit

seq = [20, 45, 45, 40, 12, 48, 67, 90, 0, 56, 12, 45, 67, 45, 34, 32, 20]

# Quadratic running time
def quad (S):
    n = len(S)
    A = [0] * n

    for j in range(n):
        total = 0
        for i in range(j+1):
            total += S[i]
        A[j] = total / (j+1)

    return A

# Use prev result
def prev (S):
    n = len(S)
    A = [0] * n

    for j in range(n):
        if j == 0:
            A[j] = S[j]
        else:
            A[j] = (A[j-1]*j + S[j]) / (j+1)
    return A

# Use Python's sum method
def summ (S):
    n = len(S)
    A = [0] * n

    for j in range(n):
        A[j] = sum(S[0:j+1])/(j+1)
    return A

def plot_func (name):
    for i in range(0, 1000000, 100000):
        t = timeit.Timer('{}(seq)'.format(name), 'from __main__ import {}, seq'.format(name))
        print(i, ',', t.timeit(number=i))

plot_func('quad')
plot_func('prev')
plot_func('summ')
```

So I'm collecting the running times of three algorithms and plotting them. My final data looked like this:

```
Input size  Quadratic   Prev    Summ
(x100000)
1   4.92E-007   7.78E-007   3.47E-007
2   1.582717351 0.603501161 0.750457885
3   3.205707528 1.176623609 1.508853766
4   4.796092943 1.76059924  2.295842737
5   6.457349465 2.34945291  3.112500982
6   8.057410897 2.947556047 3.882303307
7   9.59740446  3.520847787 4.654968896
8   11.36328988 4.122617632 5.412608518
9   12.776150393    4.703240974 6.181500295
10  14.704703677    5.282404892 6.882074295
```

When plotted, these numbers result in:

[image]

Now, according to the textbook I'm following, the functions `quad` and `summ` are supposed to run in quadratic time, while `prev` will run in linear time. I can see that `prev` is significantly faster than `quad` and somewhat faster than `summ`, but all of these look like linear functions to me! Further, there is frighteningly little gap in `summ` and `prev`.

Could someone please explain what's wrong?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't really say that anything is "wrong" ;) Maybe unexpected.

Comment: @erip Agree. That's a better way to put it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The asymptotic complexity of an algorithm means its dependence from input length. Here, you do not change the input size between runs, you just change the number of times to run each algorithm (as a parameter to `timeit()`):

```
   for i in range(0, 1000000, 100000):
        t = timeit.Timer('{}(seq)'.format(name), 'from __main__ import {}, seq'.format(name))
        print(i, ',', t.timeit(number=i))
```

To get proper comparison, change the length of your sequence between runs.

Comment: I think I heard the OP's facepalm from here.

Comment: Works as expected when changing length

Comment: @jez Seriously, that's what I just did! :D

Comment: By the way: 1) the function prev doesn't output the same as the other two, the numbers are sightly lower. I guess you have a division error here. 2) I believe summ is quadratic, because you slice the list (= creating a new one) in order to sum from 0 to j+1.